# Formsets error [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have this error `[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']`, even if the management_form is in the template, I'm using 2 forms in the template, I tried to put a prefix in the formset, but it doesn't accept prefix. This is my code. I don't know what I'm missing or if I need to make both of the forms, formsets. (**First time working with formsets**).

**view.py**

```
def DrugsPrescription(request, id):
    data = RecipeDataForm(prefix='data')
    drugs_formset = formset_factory(DrugsForm)
    patient = PatientData.objects.get(pk=id)
    errors = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = RecipeDataForm(request.POST, prefix='data')
        drugs_formset = drugs_formset(request.POST, prefix="med")
        if data.is_valid():
            info = data.save(commit=False)
            info.patient = patient
            if drugs_formset.is_valid():
                info.save()
                for form in drugs_formset.forms:
                    print form
                med = drugs_formset.save(commit=False)
                med.datos_id = info.pk
                med.save()
                success_url = reverse('/')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
            else:
                print drugs_formset.errors
        else:
            print data.errors
    return render(
        request, 'prescription.html',
         {'data': data,
         'patient': patient,
         'drugs_formset': drugs_formset,
         'errors': errors})
```

**template.html**

```
<form class="medical" id="drugs" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% crispy data %}
    <div>{{errors}}</div>
    <div id="data">
    {{ drugs_formset.management_form }}
    <table border="2">
        {% for form in drugs_formset %}
          <tr>
              {{ form }}
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to instantiate your formsets also when the request is not POST.

Also avoid using the same variable for your formset class and formset instance.

Your code should rather be:

```
def drugs_prescription(request, id):
    DrugsFormSet = formset_factory(DrugsForm)
    patient = PatientData.objects.get(pk=id)
    errors = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = RecipeDataForm(request.POST, prefix='data')
        drugs_formset = DrugsFormSet(request.POST, prefix="med")
        if data.is_valid():
            info = data.save(commit=False)
            info.patient = patient
            if drugs_formset.is_valid():
                info.save()
                for form in drugs_formset.forms:
                    print form
                med = drugs_formset.save(commit=False)
                med.datos_id = info.pk
                med.save()
                success_url = reverse('/')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
            else:
                print drugs_formset.errors
        else:
            print data.errors
    else:
        data = RecipeDataForm(prefix='data')
        drugs_formset = DrugsFormSet(prefix='med')
    return render(
        request, 'prescription.html',
         {'data': data,
         'patient': patient,
         'drugs_formset': drugs_formset,
         'errors': errors})
```

I also renamed your function from `DrugsPrescription` to `drugs_prescription` to match python style conventions.